# Compute Document Libray Size Sharepoint 2007

Tags: document-library, 2007

Please help me to compute document library size in sharepoint ?

Regards,
Shiva Reddy.p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from: http://sridharu.blogspot.com/2009/02/sharepoint-document-library-size.html

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://servername"))
{
   DataTable tbl;
   tbl = site.StorageManagementInformation(
   SPSite.StorageManagementInformationType.DocumentLibrary, 
   SPSite.StorageManagementSortOrder.Decreasing,
   SPSite.StorageManagementSortedOn.Size, 100);
   foreach (DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
   {
      foreach (DataColumn column in tbl.Columns)
      MessageBox.Show("Doc Lib Name :" + row["Title"].ToString() + "  Size (bytes): " + row["Size"].ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brain , i got same solution. The above code will give the document library size..

Answer (score 2):

Try space monitor (http://www.thesug.org/Blogs/lsuslinky/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=33&RootFolder=%2FBlogs%2Flsuslinky%2FLists%2FPosts) a great free tool to analyse storage used by your entire site.